# Cannot connect to ASP.NET database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I don't know how to connect to my SQL Server (local) from an application on ASP.NET MVC.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Connect to SQL SERVER (DbSetttings.json)

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=СМОЛЬКИНСЕРГЕЙ\\SERVER;Database=Shop;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

}

Making creation through ef migrations

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration initial 
EntityFrameworkCore\Update-DataBase
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJUsO.png)

I am new and can not understand what the error is

Comment: If it’s your default local instance you can replace СМОЛЬКИНСЕРГЕЙ\\SERVER with localhost.

Comment: Try to use the same details in SSMS and see if you can connect to it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the connection string as follows:

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=СМОЛЬКИНСЕРГЕЙ\\SERVER;Initial Catalog=Shop;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

Notice 'Server' and 'Database' are changed 'Data Source' and 'Initial Catalog'